# AWS - how to list resources a user has access to

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I'm looking for a quick and efficient way to retrieve and display the names of all existing resources a user has access to, based on their roles, policies and groups. Wondering if `aws-sdk` has any such capability to do it programmatically.

Conversely, I'm also looking for a way to list the roles and users a specific resource has granted access to based on its resource-based policy.

I'm quite new to the AWS platform, and am currently involved in a team stressing on rapid application development. Any insights and guidelines would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not have an API that returns this type of information. For example, you cannot call a Service Client method that would return a list of Amazon S3 buckets that a specific user has access to. For more information about IAM roles and permissions, check the docs here:

[Permissions required to access IAM resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_permissions-required.html)